# Manually open Featherlight Gallery with text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I'd like to display 1 or more content details in a featherlight gallery, so users can swipe or click from page to page, and then close to return to their previous tasks. The content might look something like this:

```
<div id="ContentDetails">
<div class="ach">
  <h3>Title 1</h3>
  <p>Content Item 1</p>
</div>
<div class="ach">
  <h3>Title 2</h3>
  <p>Content Item 2</p>
</div>
<div class="ach">
  <h3>Title 3</h3>
  <p>Content Item 3</p>
</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6n0a55qn/46/

I can get the single `$.featherlight($("div.ach"));` call to work, but it places *all* the text in the same lightbox -- I'd like each content item in a separate "slide." Unfortunately, the same call to `$.featherlightGallery($("div.ach"));` doesn't appear to do anything. Some questions from a really new user:

- Can `featherlightGallery()` be called manually like `featherlight()`?
- If so, what's the syntax that would separate each of those blocks into their own "slide"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got it to work. In answer to the questions above:

- Yes, `featherlightGallery()` can be called manually, like `featherlight()`. There does appear to be a distinction, though...
- It doesn't look like `featherlightGallery()` likes `<div>` content elements, at least in the current version (1.7.6) (note that the call to `featherlight()` is okay with `<div>` elements, though). I was able to create a gallery by changing the outer `<div>` elements to `<a>` guys instead, as follows:

```
<a class="slides" href=".slide-1">
  <div class="slide-1">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <p>Content Item 1</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="slides" href=".slide-2">
  <div class="slide-2">
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <p>Content Item 2</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="slides" href=".slide-3">
  <div class="slide-3">
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
    <p>Content Item 3</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

To manually call the gallery:

```
$.featherlightGallery($(".slides"));
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6n0a55qn/66/

Comment: Glad you found a way. `<div>` should work fine, but you might need to specify a target.